# Accessing Table Row From Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I currently have a bootstrap popover holding a button. The popover shows only when the mouse is over a table's `tr`.

What I want to do is to be able to access the elements for that row, is this possible.

Popover code:

```
$('.popup').popover(
    {
      placement: 'top',
      trigger: 'manual',
      delay: { show: 350, hide: 100 },
      html: true,
      content: $('#shortcuts').html(),
      title: "Quick Tasks"
    }
  ).parent().delegate('#quickDeleteBtn', 'click', function() {
      alert($(this).closest('tr').children('td').text()); // ???
});
    var timer,
        popover_parent;
    function hidePopover(elem) {
        $(elem).popover('hide');
    }
    $('.popup').hover(
        function() {
          var self = this;
          clearTimeout(timer);
          $('.popover').hide(); //Hide any open popovers on other elements.
          popover_parent = self
          //$('.popup').attr("data-content","WOOHOOOO!");
          $(self).popover('show');            
        }, 
        function() {
          var self = this;
          timer = setTimeout(function(){hidePopover(self)},250);                 
    });
    $(document).on({
      mouseenter: function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
      },
      mouseleave: function() {
        var self = this;
        timer = setTimeout(function(){hidePopover(popover_parent)},250); 
      }
    }, '.popover');
```

HTML:

```
<div class="hide" id="shortcuts">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="quickDeleteBtn" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
    </div>
```

javascript that implements popover on row:

```
rows += '<tr class="popup datarow" rel="popover">';
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here and how I am supposed to access the child elements of the `tr` I'm hovering over?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C5BjY/8/

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: I've included a fiddle in my question, http://jsfiddle.net/C5BjY/8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason I couldn't get `closest()` to work as it should. Using `parent().parent()` to get to the containing `.popover` divider, then using `prev()` to get the previous `tr` element seems to do the trick however.

Just change:

```
alert($(this).closest('tr').children('td').text());
```

To:

```
alert($(this).parent().parent().prev('tr').children('td').text());
```

[**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/C5BjY/10/).

---

As a side note, as your Fiddle uses jQuery 1.10.1 you should change `delegate()` to [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
on('click', '#quickDeleteBtn', function(index) { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks, works great! Can't award bounty after 24 hours unfortunately.

Comment: @SandeepBansal Or you could use the `popover_parent` var, check my answer :p

Comment: The reason that it cannot find `closest` is that the popover is added to the page DOM directly. `closest` will work if you give the container parameter to which popover is added.

Comment: The answer will not work if `tr` is nested deeper than its current level, if it is inside more divs.

Comment: @user568109 the popover is added directly after the parent. The parent is the `tr`. Regardless of how nested the `tr` is, the `tr` will always be directly before the popover.

Comment: What you say is not correct, popover is added directly after the parent only if `container` parameter is not given. Suppose the OP decides to use that parameter then it will not work. The solution may work here, but it is safer/more correct to use the option that has been provided already.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/C5BjY/20/) I have fixed it.
You just have to pass the container option in which the popover element is added for the popover

```
$('.popup').each(function (index) {
    console.log(index + ": " + $(this).text());
    $(this).popover({
        placement: 'top',
        trigger: 'manual',
        delay: {
            show: 350,
            hide: 100
        },
        html: true,
        content: $('#shortcuts').html(),
        title: "Quick Tasks",
        container: '#' + this.id
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your button click alert, $(this) refers to the button itself. In the DOM hierarchy, the popover html is nowhere near your hovered tr.

Add a handler to the list item to store itself in a global variable and access that from the click event. See the forked fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/edQnr/3/).

First we declare a global (at the very top):

```
var hovered;
```

Then we add a mouseover handler to the list item. Note that using 'on' means every newly generated list item will also receive this handler:

```
$('body').on('mouseover', '.popup', function() {
      hovered = $(this);   
 });
```

Then we can alert the needed data from within the button click event:

```
alert(hovered.text());
```

Answer (score 0):

See here **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C5BjY/15/)**

by removing the delegate and using the id to find the button and attaching it to a click handler by making the popover makes it easier to track it

```
$(self).popover('show');
$('#quickDeleteBtn').click(function(){
    alert($(self).text());
});
```

also note

```
$('#shortcuts').remove();
```

because you were using the button in the popover with the same ID in the `#shortcuts` we couldn't select it first, now we remove it we can

Answer (score 0):

You already have the correct element in your code. Just reuse the `popover_parent` variable and you are all set :) [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/KcEV7/3/)

```
alert($(popover_parent).text());
```

Or you could do something around like this :

```
$('.popup').hover(

    function () {
        var self = this;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $('.popover').hide(); //Hide any open popovers on other elements.
        $('#quickDeleteBtn').data('target', '');
        popover_parent = self;

        //$('.popup').attr("data-content","WOOHOOOO!");
        $('#quickDeleteBtn').data('target', $(self));
        $(self).popover('show');

    },

    function () {
        var self = this;
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $('#quickDeleteBtn').data('target', '');
            hidePopover(self)
        }, 250);
    });
    $(document).on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            var self = this;
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                $('#quickDeleteBtn').data('target', '');
                hidePopover(popover_parent)
            }, 250);
        }
    }, '.popover');
```

I just store the element clicked in your #quickDeleteBtn then use the link.
[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/KcEV7/)